# F# static member

Tags: f#

I was working through the PDC 2008 F# videos and seem to run into a problem

```
type StockAnalyzer (lprices, days) =
let prices =
    lprices
    |> Seq.map snd
    |> Seq.take days
 static member GetAnalyzers(tickers, days) = 
    tickers
    |> Seq.map loadPrices
    |> Seq.map (fun prices -> new StockAnalyzer(prices, days))

 member s.Return = 
    let lastPrice = prices |> Seq.nth 0
    let startPrice = prices |> Seq.nth (days - 1)
    lastPrice / startPrice - 1.
```

I am getting an error at the static.

> GetStockPrices.fs(31,6): error FS0010: Unexpected keyword 'static' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token.

Does anyone know if they have changed the syntax or can spot what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 15):

F# uses significant white space.  Add a space in front of "let prices =".  The compiler is trying to figure out why you have a static member of "prices", because the only preceding line with less indentation is "let prices =".

You may want to use more indentation, just for clarity.

```
type StockAnalyzer (lprices, days) =
   let prices =
      lprices
      |> Seq.map snd
      |> Seq.take days

   static member GetAnalyzers(tickers, days) = 
      tickers
      |> Seq.map loadPrices
      |> Seq.map (fun prices -> new StockAnalyzer(prices, days))

   member s.Return = 
      let lastPrice = prices |> Seq.nth 0
      let startPrice = prices |> Seq.nth (days - 1)
      lastPrice / startPrice - 1.
```

Answer (score 7):

The indentation before the word `static` is confusing the compiler and it's trying to interpret it as part of the `let` expression. The `let` expression should be indented and the member definitions should be in line with it.